# Copying data giving using getPrimaryClip() giving { text/plain {NULL} }

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I am getting `{ text/plain {NULL} }` when I am using `ClipData` but if I use deprecated method `mClipboard.getText()` it is working just fine.

```
if (mClipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
    ClipData clipData = mClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
    Log.d(TAG, clipData.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, mClipboard.getText());
}
```

**Update**

Issue exists in Samsung galaxy Tab 3.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Tab 3]

Comment: Hey unable to reproduce this issue. I just copied and past your code and tested on a  device it runs as supposed to. here is a screenshot
http://imgur.com/EBPsLVP
How do you copy the data and have you tested it on a real device?

Comment: @ProblemSlover It is coming on Samsung Galaxy S4 and Galaxy Tab. I'll post the screenshot tomorrow.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: @ProblemSlover Not really. In any case `ClipData.Item` is coming null. So `item.coerceToText(this)` and `item.getText()` are both null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of your problem is unknown. since it works on a device which I tested on (S6 5.0). You may want to look at the implementation of deprecated `getText()` method:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    ClipData clip = getPrimaryClip();
    if (clip != null && clip.getItemCount() > 0) {
        return clip.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(mContext);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In order to obtain the text It uses the method coerceToText() . according to description of this method:

```
     * Turn this item into text, regardless of the type of data it
     * actually contains.
```

Therefore , I presume the deprecation of method getText() is due to a performance concern or something else.

Anyway. Since method `getText()` uses API which is not deprecated,  as a workaround you can use some part of the source of this method(specifically, method `coerceToText()` )  if calling recommended API returns null:

```
ClipboardManager mclipboard =(ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
boolean isTextPlain = mclipboard.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
    CharSequence text = null;
if (isTextPlain){
    ClipData clipData = mclipboard.getPrimaryClip();
    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
    if (  item!= null ){
        text = item.getText();
        if (text == null){
            // taken from source of clipData.getText() method
            text =  item.coerceToText(this);
        }
    }
}
```