# How to get the text from a ClipData object?

Tags: android, clipboard

In Android, the way to get the clipboard text [used to be simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651184/set-text-and-get-text-from-clipboard):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
String text = clipboard.getText();
```

The `getText()` method has now been deprecated, and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#getText()) says to use `getPrimaryClip()` instead:

> getText()
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use getPrimaryClip() instead. This retrieves the primary clip and tries to coerce it to a string.

However, `getPrimaryClip()` returns a `ClipData` object, and it is not clear how to get the text content in this object. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    ClipData clip = getPrimaryClip();
    if (clip != null && clip.getItemCount() > 0) {
        return clip.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(mContext);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33605037/5993410)